# How to convert a string to float with "tail"?

Tags: php, string, floating-point, integer, decimal

I have a problem with converting string to float.

```
print gettype($value[$id]); //returns string

var_dump($value[$id]);//returns string '34,7140' (length=7)

$float = floatval($value[$id]); 

print gettype($float);//returns double

var_dump($float);//returns float 34

echo $float;//returns 34
```

I don't understand why "34" ? Why $float is not '34,7140'?  
 How can I get $float = 34,7140 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that floats are expected to be in the English format with a `.` separating the decimal part, not a comma. If the format is always the same with a single comma, use this:

```
$float = (float)str_replace(',', '.', $value);
```

Comment: wouldn't that turn the thousand separator into a decimal point (i.e. 34.714). Should just remove the comma altogether, no?

Comment: @Ben That doesn't look like a thousand separator to me.

Answer (score 1):

The decimal separator in PHP (and most other computer languages) is the dot, not the comma:

- http://es2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

**Update:** [floatval()](http://es2.php.net/floatval) stops parsing the string as soon as it finds a non-numeric character. This is the example from the manual:

```
<?php
$var = '122.34343The';
$float_value_of_var = floatval($var);
echo $float_value_of_var; // 122.34343
?>
```

If you need to extract a number that's not in English format, you have to write your own code. Here's a suggestion:

```
function to_decimal($string, $decimal_separator=',', $thousand_separator='.'){
    $value = strtr($string, array(
        $decimal_separator => '.',
        $thousand_separator => '',
    ));
    if( !is_numeric($value) ){
        return NAN;
    }
    return floatval($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because "34,7140" is a string, as it contains a comma character.

You could use `$float = floatval(str_replace(',', '', $value[$id]));` to remove the comma character, or `$float = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $value[$id]));` to replace the comma with a decimal point, hence forcing PHP to interpret the number as 34.7140.