# adding decimal values with php

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$sum=0;
while($row=oci_fetch_row($que))
{

$sum+=$row[8];
}

echo number_format((float)$sum,2,",","").'<br>';
```

there are 3 rows with values '7.01' '43.76' '11.64'
echo prints 61.00 instead of 62.41.
Why?
The corresponding to mySql code works like a charm.....
SOLVED.....
[How to convert a string to float with "tail"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174562/how-to-convert-a-string-to-float-with-tail)
thanks guys for your time

Comment: A value from the oracle db. I think its varchar type.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic.  See [Floating point precision](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) and [Why don’t my numbers add up?](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

```
echo serialize(7.01);
echo serialize(43.76);
echo serialize(11.64);;
```

Try [BC Match Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) or round to 2 decimal places first:

```
echo round(7.01, 2) + round(43.76, 2) + round(11.64, 2);
//$sum += round($row[8], 2);
```

Comment: The references helped me understand a lot.